# Sticky Sidebar with end point

Tags: jquery, html, sticky

**Update with image:**
[image]

I'm using this code to sticky a div into determined area:

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  var $sidebar = $("#artist"),
    $window = $(window),
    $footer = $("#contact-box"), // use your footer ID here
    offset = $sidebar.offset(),
    foffset = $footer.height(),
    threshold = foffset.height - $sidebar.height() - offset.top,
    topPadding = 15;

  $window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > threshold) {
      $sidebar.stop().animate({
        marginTop: threshold
      }, 900);
    } else if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
      $sidebar.stop().animate({
        marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
      }, 900);
    } else {
      $sidebar.stop().animate({
        marginTop: 0
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="variable-content-container">
  <div id="contact-box">

    <div id="contact-spacer"></div>
    <!--ends ------------------------->



    <div id="acervo-variable-head">
      <div id="acervo-middle-arrow-wrapper"><span id="acervo-recents">dossiê</span></div>
    </div>
    <!-- acervo-variable-head ends ------------------------->


    <div id="dossie-locations">
      <div id="artist"><img src="snippets/artist.jpg" width="224" height="341" alt="" /></div>
      <div id="dossie-area">
        <span class="destaque">John Doe</span> <br /> Example #01 <br />
        <span class="destaque">Example 02</span> FFFFF <br />
        <span class="destaque">Example text:</span> Example Test <br />
        <span class="destaque">Example:</span> Example <br /> Example <br /><br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed faucibus sed dui nec ornare. Nullam vel gravida felis. Etiam laoreet lectus sed nisl sodales venenatis. Vivamus
        facilisis, dui sit amet ultrices condimentum, lectus sapien congue libero, aliquam efficitur mauris nisi vitae dui. Integer suscipit ultricies turpis, sed mollis tortor aliquet sed. Ut ultrices erat ut velit porttitor mollis. Pellentesque aliquet
        imperdiet libero, eu scelerisque leo auctor id. Aenean eget gravida sapien. Vestibulum at nibh ullamcorper, pharetra nunc sed, varius tellus. Sed lobortis sem enim, convallis mattis tortor imperdiet eu. Integer a consectetur erat. Nulla facilisi.
        Nunc sit amet ipsum sapien. Pellentesque dignissim mi ac nunc malesuada viverra. Morbi nec lorem eget dui vehicula mollis. <br /><br /><br />
      </div>
      <!--dossie-area-->
    </div>
    <!--dossie-locations-->


  </div>
  <!--contact-box ends ------------------------->
</div>
<!--variable-content-container ends ------------------------->
```

The **#contact-box** is the container and **#artist** is the sticky. I need that sticky stop at 10px of the **contact-box** end. But the **div#artist** is expanding size of the **contact-box** div.

**UPDATE CSS**

```
#artist {
width: 224px;
height: 341px;
float: left;
position: relative;

#contact-box {
    height: auto;
    min-width: auto;
    min-height: 536px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #100b0f;
    background-image: url(../sndippets/brown-glow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto; /*To make div height according content*/
}
```

Comment: If it is expanding size of parent div maybe you should look for cause of this issue in `CSS` markup? try setting `div#artist` `position` to `relative` and playing with CSS

Comment: Updated CSS, div#artist with position = relative not working =[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added `bottomPadding = 40;`. This sets the stopping point relative to the bottom of the dossie-area.

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  var $sidebar = $("#artist"),
    $window = $(window),
    $footer = $("#contact-box"), // use your footer ID here
    offset = $sidebar.offset(),
    foffset = $footer.height(),
    threshold = foffset.height - $sidebar.height() - offset.top,
    topPadding = 15,
    bottomPadding = 40,
    $dossieArea = $("#dossie-area"),
    dossieAreaHeight = $dossieArea.height(),
    sidebarHeight = $sidebar.height();

  $window.scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop < (dossieAreaHeight - sidebarHeight - bottomPadding)) {
      if (scrollTop > threshold) {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
          marginTop: threshold
        }, 900);
      } else if (scrollTop > offset.top) {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
          marginTop: scrollTop - offset.top + topPadding
        }, 900);
      } else {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
          marginTop: 0
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#artist {
  float: left;
}

#artist img {
  width: 112px;
  height: 170px;
  float: left;
}

#dossie-area {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
}

#contact-box {
  height: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  min-height: 536px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /*background-color: #100b0f; */
  background-image: url(../sndippets/brown-glow.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  /*To make div height according content*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="variable-content-container">
  <div id="contact-box">

    <div id="contact-spacer"></div>
    <!--ends ------------------------->

    <div id="acervo-variable-head">
      <div id="acervo-middle-arrow-wrapper"><span id="acervo-recents">dossiê</span></div>
    </div>
    <!-- acervo-variable-head ends ------------------------->


    <div id="dossie-locations">
      <div id="artist"><img src="https://www.google.co.nz/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="" /></div>
      <div id="dossie-area">
        <span class="destaque">John Doe</span> <br /> Example #01 <br />
        <span class="destaque">Example 02</span> FFFFF <br />
        <span class="destaque">Example text:</span> Example Test <br />
        <span class="destaque">Example:</span> Example <br /> Example <br /><br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed faucibus sed dui nec ornare. Nullam vel gravida felis. Etiam laoreet lectus sed nisl sodales venenatis. Vivamus
        facilisis, dui sit amet ultrices condimentum, lectus sapien congue libero, aliquam efficitur mauris nisi vitae dui. Integer suscipit ultricies turpis, sed mollis tortor aliquet sed. Ut ultrices erat ut velit porttitor mollis. Pellentesque aliquet
        imperdiet libero, eu scelerisque leo auctor id. Aenean eget gravida sapien. Vestibulum at nibh ullamcorper, pharetra nunc sed, varius tellus. Sed lobortis sem enim, convallis mattis tortor imperdiet eu. Integer a consectetur erat. Nulla facilisi.
        Nunc sit amet ipsum sapien. Pellentesque dignissim mi ac nunc malesuada viverra. Morbi nec lorem eget dui vehicula mollis. <br /><br /><br />
      </div>
      <!--dossie-area-->
    </div>
    <!--dossie-locations-->

  </div>
  <!--contact-box ends ------------------------->
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed faucibus sed dui nec ornare. Nullam vel gravida felis. Etiam laoreet lectus sed nisl sodales venenatis. Vivamus facilisis, dui sit amet ultrices condimentum, lectus sapien congue libero, aliquam
    efficitur mauris nisi vitae dui. Integer suscipit ultricies turpis, sed mollis tortor aliquet sed. Ut ultrices erat ut velit porttitor mollis. Pellentesque aliquet imperdiet libero, eu scelerisque leo auctor id. Aenean eget gravida sapien. Vestibulum
    at nibh ullamcorper, pharetra nunc sed, varius tellus. Sed lobortis sem enim, convallis mattis tortor imperdiet eu. Integer a consectetur erat. Nulla facilisi. Nunc sit amet ipsum sapien. Pellentesque dignissim mi ac nunc malesuada viverra. Morbi
    nec lorem eget dui vehicula mollis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed faucibus sed dui nec ornare. Nullam vel gravida felis. Etiam laoreet lectus sed nisl sodales venenatis. Vivamus facilisis, dui sit amet ultrices condimentum,
    lectus sapien congue libero, aliquam efficitur mauris nisi vitae dui. Integer suscipit ultricies turpis, sed mollis tortor aliquet sed. Ut ultrices erat ut velit porttitor mollis. Pellentesque aliquet imperdiet libero, eu scelerisque leo auctor id.
    Aenean eget gravida sapien. Vestibulum at nibh ullamcorper, pharetra nunc sed, varius tellus. Sed lobortis sem enim, convallis mattis tortor imperdiet eu. Integer a consectetur erat. Nulla facilisi. Nunc sit amet ipsum sapien. Pellentesque dignissim
    mi ac nunc malesuada viverra. Morbi nec lorem eget dui vehicula mollis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed faucibus sed dui nec ornare. Nullam vel gravida felis. Etiam laoreet lectus sed nisl sodales venenatis. Vivamus facilisis,
    dui sit amet ultrices condimentum, lectus sapien congue libero, aliquam efficitur mauris nisi vitae dui. Integer suscipit ultricies turpis, sed mollis tortor aliquet sed. Ut ultrices erat ut velit porttitor mollis. Pellentesque aliquet imperdiet libero,
    eu scelerisque leo auctor id. Aenean eget gravida sapien. Vestibulum at nibh ullamcorper, pharetra nunc sed, varius tellus. Sed lobortis sem enim, convallis mattis tortor imperdiet eu. Integer a consectetur erat. Nulla facilisi. Nunc sit </div>
</div>
<!--variable-content-container ends ------------------------->
```

Comment: Actually I need that the contact-box div to have a height limit using jquery, so the div artist can stop at 10px from the end of that div. I can not set max-height of the div using css because the div has variable content inside.

Comment: if the div has variable content then how do you know what the height limit should be?

Comment: The height limit must be equal to the size of the "# dossie-area" div. Because this div contains text that can be variable.

Comment: I expect that is still not what you want. I am not clear on the problem you want to solve. I can see things I believe are wrong, but I don't know if they are what you want to change, or perhaps it is something else. If you want to include screenshots of what it does currently, and one of what it should look like, I will be able to better understand the problem.

Comment: Updated with a example image.

Comment: You mean like this?  (I'll tidy my code a little if this is what you want)

Comment: Just tidied the code to make it more generally applicable

Comment: Yes, just like that.